# Page scroll on click of an arrow which has hash tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am looking for a jquery script to 'animate/scroll' within a page, when clicked on an arrow which 'hash' tag:

Below is the arrow code am placing above a background-image in html

```
<div style="margin-top:380px;">
    <a href="#transparency">
        <div class="arrow-down-light-blue"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Javascript in html page

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Could any please help me with providing a jquery script for this one?

Comment: Please include code you have tried; even if it is not working.  It gives us a clearer idea of what you are looking for, and you will get a better and quicker answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code 
Use [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to bind `click` event and use [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) to scroll down to the desire HTML element

Change your HTML as below

```
 <div style="margin-top:380px;">
    <a id="anchorID" class="anchorClick" href="#transparency">
        <div class="arrow-down-light-blue">Click here</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div style="height:500px"></div>
<div id="transparency"> your transparency div here </div>

<div style="margin-top:380px;">
    <a id="anchorID1" class="anchorClick" href="#transparency1">
        <div class="arrow-down-light-blue">Click here</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div style="height:500px"></div>
<div id="transparency1" style="margin-bottom:100px;"> your transparency.1 div here </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".anchorClick").click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top // UPDATED LINE
      }, 2000);
   });
});
```

** **And DO NOT forget to add jQuery Library at the top of the HTML page in `<head>` tag :)**

**Updated Answer :** use `ClassName` selector

**[See the updated JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/stLL9b3j/4/)**

Comment: Added the id="anchorID" as you have mentioned, also updated the javascript, it is not working.

Comment: It's working for me - See working Demo - click here - http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/stLL9b3j/

Comment: when click on the buttons they are working. But only first arrow scrolls, but the others below that, when clicked 'jumps' to that anchored section.

Below are the id names am calling:
#transparency{
 }

#onesize{
 }

#greatpeople{
 }

#thevalue{
 }

#takeaction{
 }

Comment: @Prog.Awaiting for your reply.

Comment: @sharath-designer did you use `scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top` ??

Comment: @sharath-designer please make js fiddle so I can help you more

Comment: @Prog-Yes, that is what i have used: scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top

After every 900px (height) i place the arrow. The 1st arrow scroll with smooth action, but all arrows after that, it just jumps to so and so section.

Comment: @Sharath-designer See the updated js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/stLL9b3j/4/

Comment: @Prog-Thank you so much for your time, it is working now....Could you please explain what went wrong there? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

took out the divs with the margin top for demonstartion, this works on classes so is expandable. edited to add back to top

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".anchor").click(function(e){
      $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 1000);
   });
});
```

```css
#top{background-color:red;}
#middle{background-color:yellow;}
#bottom{background-color:green;}
div.block{height:400px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toppage"></div>
<a class="anchor" href="#top"> 
        <div class="arrow-down-light-blue">top</div>
    </a>


    <a class="anchor" href="#middle">
        <div class="arrow-down-light-blue">middle</div>
   

    <a class="anchor" href="#bottom">
        <div class="arrow-down-light-blue">bottom</div>
    </a>

<div class="block" id="top">The top
  <a class="anchor" href="#toppage"> Back to top</a>
      </div>
<div class="block" id="middle">The middle
      <a class="anchor" href="#toppage"> Back to top</a>
      </div>
<div  class="block" id="bottom">The bottom
      <a class="anchor" href="#toppage"> Back to top</a>
      </div>
```